# jest - separate tests into another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Is it possible to separate jest's test function into another file or do they have to be inside the executing file?

For example:

**test_file.js**

```
function tests (input)
{
    it(
        "should pass",
        function ()
        {
            expect(input).toBeTrue()
        }
    )
    // more test functions
}
module.exports = tests
```

**main.js**

```
const tests = require("./test_file.js")

describe(
    "test block 1",
    function ()
    {
        let input

        beforeAll( () => input = true )

        tests(input)
    }
)
```

right now, `input` is always undefined

Comment: it can be done just like you wrote it.

Comment: @felixmosh It doesn't seem to receive the input properly. I always get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add some logs and look at the order in which this code is executed.

`main.test.js`:

```js
const tests = require('./test_file.js');
console.log('000');
describe('test block 1', function() {
  let input;
  console.log('111');
  beforeAll(() => {
    console.log('222');
    input = true;
  });
  tests(input);
});
```

`test_file.js`:

```js
console.log('333');
function tests(input) {
  console.log('444');
  it('should pass', function() {
    console.log('555');
    expect(input).toBeTruthy();
  });
}
module.exports = tests;
```

Test result:

```sh
 FAIL  src/stackoverflow/59520741/main.test.js (9.747s)
  test block 1
    ✕ should pass (7ms)

  ● test block 1 › should pass

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: undefined

      4 |   it('should pass', function() {
      5 |     console.log('555');
    > 6 |     expect(input).toBeTruthy();
        |                   ^
      7 |   });
      8 | }
      9 | module.exports = tests;

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/stackoverflow/59520741/test_file.js:6:19)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59520741/test_file.js:1
    333

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59520741/main.test.js:2
    000

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59520741/main.test.js:5
    111

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59520741/test_file.js:3
    444

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59520741/main.test.js:7
    222

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59520741/test_file.js:5
    555

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.015s
```

Now, we know. The `tests` function will execute before the test runner of jest collect the test cases. This means your `tests` function just declares the test cases('111' and '444' phrase). At this time, the `beforeAll` hook doesn't execute yet. The value of `input` variable is still `undefined` and passed into `tests` function.

After the `tests` function executed, the test cases are declared. The test runner will collect these test cases and run them in a normal way. The `beforeAll` hook will execute firstly('222' phrase).